# utf-8 latin1 problem charset collation

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

If I am sending utf-8 data to a mysql db which has a charset of utf-8 but a collation of latin1 would that be a problem? and why?

what does the collation do in this case?

I am getting mangled up data when I extract it from the db, will a collation change fix that?

**Update**

The mangled data in the DB is for example like this:

```
 TÃ¶st
```

It should be like:

```
Täst
```

correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your error: make sure you send `SET NAMES utf8` to your SQL server before INSERTing the data.

Comment: can you explain what that will do for me? Right before I send my insert string to mysql?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be a problem, per-se. The collation controls things like sort order & how comparisons are accomplished.

It is likely that the mangled data is being caused by something else.

Answer (score 1):

Collation relates to how different characters will be compared. This could cause issues if you are comparing utf-8 data with a latin1 collation since you may get different results than what you expect. Changing the collation will not stop the data from being mangled.